# Unchanging object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, web-sql

I have interesting mistake in JavaScript. I can't change any property of the object.
 
After selection in Web SQL it returns me an object, but when I try to change or delete any property nothing happens. This example creates object "node" (working in Chrome):

```js
var getNode = function(callback){database = openDatabase('db', "1", "object store", 10);
    database.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (NodeId int, NodeName text)", [], function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("insert into name (NodeId,NodeName) values (1,'node')",[],function(tx){
       tx.executeSql("select * from name where NodeId=1",[],function(tx,res){
        callback(res.rows.item(0));
       });
      });
     }, {});
    });
} 
getNode(function(node){
   node.NodeId=22;//change nothing
   delete node.NodeId;//return true, but doesn't delete
   console.log(node);
});
```

Why I can't change the property? And how can I do it?

Comment: Why you say do not work? You are assigning 22, so it should be return 22. Did you debug before assigning "22", if node.NodeId is "1"?

Comment: Yes I debug before assinging, node.NodeId is 1, then I do `node.NodeId=22`, it return "22", but when I check it again by `console.log` or `alert` it is still "22".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous, so it's not executing in the order it appears. Because `node=res.rows.item(0);` is in a callback that gets run after your `executeSql`s are done, it is setting `node` to the response *after*  `node.NodeId = 22;` etc.

Think of it like this:

1. Set node to {}
2. executeSql
3. Set node.NodeId to 22 (and delete node.NodeId)
4. Get response from #2's executeSql and set node to the first row of the response, overwriting #3's set completely

Step four (which is your 7th line in your example) is happening *after* step 3 (which is your 14/15th lines).

To get around it, you need to alter `node` *after* you get your callback. You can do this by using your own callback to be executed when you want. Something like this:

```
var node = {};
var getNode = function(callback){
    var database = openDatabase('db', "1", "object store", 10);
    database.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (NodeId int, NodeName text)", [], function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("insert into name (NodeId,NodeName) values (1,'node')",[],function(tx){
       tx.executeSql("select * from name where NodeId=1",[],function(tx,res){
         // Stringify/Parse the item so we can manipulate it in the callback
         node = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.rows.item(0)));
         // Now that we've set node, let's call the callback we passed in.
         callback && callback();
       });
      });
     }, {});
    });
};
// Call get node and pass a function that will be executed
// _after_ the data is asynchronously retrieved
getNode(function(){
  node.NodeId=22;
  delete node.NodeId;
  console.log(node); // Now, node.NodeId has been deleted
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, previous example was bad. But the problem isn't in asynchrony, I changed example but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexFrost Well, even your updated example still has the same asynchronous issue. When you call `f()` your following lines _still_ get executed before the callbacks in your function do. I'll update my answer to show you what you would have to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You example is good. But it doesn't delete `node.NodeId`.

Comment: @AlexFrost Sure it does. Here's a working example using `setTimeout` since I don't have your database. As you can see in your console, the output object _does not_ have a `NodeId` property: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/qTKHF/

Comment: This database is in Google Chrome and Safari by default. And this example doesn't work only after selection in Web SQL. But unfortunately I need to change node after this selection.

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't played much with web sql, so I'm not sure why you can't change properties of the Object returned (there's probably perfectly valid reasons, such as manipulating the database, not the local copy). Regardless, you can dereference it by assigning the values to a new object, or stringify/parsing it. I've updated the JSfiddle and my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/qTKHF/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the next problem, lets view your example.

How it looks:

1. You open database connection
2. You init node object
3. You execute the **asynchronous** transaction
4. You add field NodeId to node object
5. You try to delete the object field

You think that it will be works like 1-2-3-4-5, but it works like 1-2-4-5-3;

P.S. If you need synchronous code try to use openDatabaseSync and etc.,but still remember that openDatabaseSync works only in Worker (HTML5 Worker) IO, not user IO;

P.S.S IO === input/output

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, previous example was bad. But the problem isn't in asynchrony, I changed example but it still doesn't work.